# Test Amazon S3 and Redshift

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, aws-sdk, data-migration

Currently I am trying to figure out a strategy to automate the below testing scenarios:

1. Compare data integrity between a set of files between On premise server and Amazon S3 (csv) i.e. comparing two file's entire content while they are residing in two diff server.

   My thought: I have thought of using Java to compare both, but not sure bow to perform run time comparison between two diff servers. Otherwise I have to bring both of the files into same server for comparison.
2. Compare data integrity between Amazon S3 and Amazon Redshift (After data loaded from S3 to Redshift). Can I use Java to query Amazon S3 object and create a table first and then compare with Redshift? But I think although they are part of the same environment S3 and Redshift are 2 diff servers.

Please suggest if there is any SIT test framework to test On-premise to AWS Cloud migration.

Comment: You have to be more precise what you mean by integrity. Is it that you have to compare it totals of a certain column are the same, or more like checksum on entire file? Because you need to handle these differently. For example for querying files in S3 you could use AWS Athena

Comment: Thanks Adam. By integrity I meant comparing data between 2 files i.e. for all columns across all records. Like a MINUS in SQL.

Comment: Then I'd use dedicated streaming technology or an ETL tool, depending if it has to be real time or can be batch. For ETL, go with Talend, as it is Java based, and you mentioned this technology. For real time you have plenty of options, Spark Streaming, Apache Storm, or if you want to use AWS technologies, then it's probably possible using Kinesis Streams.
What I would do: load both files to S3 and then Redshift and compare using regular SQL. Not optimal, but easiest to implement for me. Option 2: Load both files to two different buckets in S3 and learn AWS Athena (don't know it, hence learn)

Comment: Thanks for sharing the options Adam. However, for option 1: As I am dealing with large data there will be significant cost involved to store in Redshift and my team is expecting a kind of solution where i can read the data in on premise server and S3 using AWS CLI and compare them in run time. And for option 2 the issue is: I think Amazon Athena is not available in the region we are working i.e. eu-west-1. Could you pls let me know how the data from on premise server can be accessed using AWS CLI. Thanks.